# Magento 2: Error on Product Detail Page

Tags: magento2, checkout, paypal, magento-community, wamp

I'm getting below `JS Error` on Product Detail Page which is from

```
paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js
```

[image]

Anybody faced this kind of JS error on Local `WAMP` (Windows 10)?

It's related to `Paypal`.

Answer (score -1):

You can give the permission of all your file to `644` and folder to `755` and run again.

Comment: I'm using Magento 2 on WAMP Windows 10